# Good idea to predefine multiple parameters in method

Tags: c#

I was wondering about coding practices, and came up witha  question. Is it a good idea to predefine multiple parameters within one method - so when you call that method you don't have to pass values if the value is predefined and correct.
i.e.

```
     private void ErrorMessage
     (bool isEmpty = false, bool fromAccEmpty = false, bool toAccEmpty = false){}
```

So when you call it you can either call it via

```
ErrorMessage();
```

or

```
ErrorMessage(true, false, true);
```

Comment: Did you [see this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: Off-topic for SO (I think) but few considerations: how often you will omit those parameters? If you use defaults more often then not then you may consider to use them (with all their disadvantages, don't ignore them). Second considerations: such boolean parameters mess should be avoided even more. Use (at least) enum flags or force yourself to use named parameters, calling point is absolutely obscure.

Comment: I use the default values more times than i do not, however each bool has a different if condition.

Comment: Kan each bool is meaningful, of course, but at calling point you need to stop and think and check and think again to remember 3rd bool meaning. Someone else reading your code will find it even more confusing. That's why - for example - `ErrorMessage(ErrorMessageOptions.IsEmpty|ErrorMessageOptions.ToAccEmpty)` is better (and extensible if you add more options). At least you should force yourself to use `ErrorMessage(isEmpty: true, toAccEmpty: true);`. Also consider default parameters drawbacks: if you change it you need to recompile calling code and you may need to manually check each call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be an alternate for you:

```
public class ErrorMessage
    {
        public bool isEmpty = false;
        public bool fromAccEmpty = false;
        public bool toAccEmpty = false;
    }
private void ShowErrorMessage(ErrorMessage errorObject)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
```

Why i suggest this:
Consider the op's code:

**#** If we call the method as he stated in the question (`Positional arguments`) we cannot call the method by specifying value for second parameter without giving value to the first one.

**#** This can be avoided by using `Named arguments` as like the following:

```
    ErrorMessage(fromAccEmpty :true);
```

Hence we can assign value to the second parameter only, others will be default. We can simply use the suggested method without these issues and confusions; consider the following snippets:

```
ErrorMessage errorBoject = new ErrorMessage();
ShowErrorMessage(errorBoject);// All default values ware assigned
errorBoject.toAccEmpty = true;
ShowErrorMessage(errorBoject); // call with value for last parameter only rest are default
errorBoject.isEmpty = true;
ShowErrorMessage(errorBoject); // only the second value is default rest of them have values
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but to expand on why its a good idea- multiple parameters with default values makes it impossible to change, say, the 3rd parameter from default without having to explicitly state values for the first two.

Comment: @esmoore68: please take a look ; i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

one thing to think about is this. When you see

```
ErrorMessage(true, false, true, false);
```

in the code 2 yrs from now. What does it mean? Also did you get the flags in the correct order. Although its more long-winded maybe

```
FribbleErrorMessage(); // some flag = true
FrobbleErrorMessage(); // some flag = false
....
```

is clearer. (Yes I know you would need 16 methods for all combinations or 4 flags - but maybe there are common ones to be called out, and reduce the number of flags)

Another idea is replace the bools by enums

```
ErrorMessage(IsError.True, EmptyAcc.False,..);
```

Now you can see what they mean and the compiler will ensure you pass the correct things

Or un-lucky's suggestion of passing a parameter block of some sort

```
 ErrorMessage(new ErrorControl{IsEmpty=true});
```

Note that many people (including me) fronw on default arg values as opposed to overloads. Why? Because if you want to change the default behavior you have to recompile the callers, maybe not a problem for you but in general is makes encapsulation a little weaker (Same reason why you should have public get;set; accessors instead of naked public fields)